# display username with agnoster theme

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have recently installed agnoster theme with Oh-My-Bash, and it works. Except I don't see my user name in terminal, and I would like to! If possible, I'd like to display time too, like this:

[image]

I have already searched topics about this problem, but people look for doing the opposite: they want to hide their user name.

I've looked the .bashrc and the comments, but it seems there is nothing relevant about this specific matter. Same thing with the README file from github.

What more can I try ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is the script that actually builds the prompt and it is shipped with the theme.

With the theme you installed, the user is only displayed in certain specific cases. You can check the logic behind that directly [here](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/blob/master/themes/agnoster/agnoster.theme.sh#L232-L234) in the source code.

To answer the *where to look* question, the short answer is in the script inside the themes folder of the agnoster folder of oh-my-bash. Depending on how you installed oh-my-bash this will vary. I'd check in `~/.oh-my-bash/themes/agnoster` and then modify the prompt script as needed. For example, you could simply disable the checks that only show the username in specific cases.

Comment: Yeah it was excatly that. So I've just modified the prompt_context() function in the script of ~/.oh-my-bash/themes/agnoster. Since I am not an expert on this code, I've just applied the following change in if condition:

if [[ $user == $DEFAULT_USER || $user != $DEFAULT_USER || -n $SSH_CLIENT ]];

Thanks for your help ! :D

Comment: For displaying time, I have modified like this:
prompt_segment green white " [\A] $user@\h " (or " \! [\A] $user@\h " if we want history lines too)
but I would like to display time  in a different color. Any idea ?

Comment: @mania, happy to hear I was able to help. Please consider marking an answer as acceptable and when asking for new things I think it is best to open a new question on StackExchange to avoid long discussions. To provide you with a hint, you could adopt the method [prompt_segment](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/blob/master/themes/agnoster/agnoster.theme.sh#L156-L178) method to print the time. This method accepts back- and foreground color as arguments, which you can see examples for when searching for usages.